# Translate WooCommerce strings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, hook-woocommerce

I try to translate missing strings in WooCommerce. I use Loco translate but these strings are not there. I could add one filter, but I don't know which hooks I have to use

"Coupon Code"
"Code here"
"Apply coupon"
"Update cart"
"Back to cart"
"Your order"
"Related"

I could successfully translate "Related Products" with this filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_related_products_heading',function(){

   return 'Services connexes';

});
```

Which filter can I use for the other strings or where can I find these?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce - Translate a word on the Checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559778/woocommerce-translate-a-word-on-the-checkout-page)

Answer (score 0):

The best filter to fit here is `gettext_{$domain}` for translating [specific domain](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext_domain/)/plugin-related texts.

```
add_filter('gettext_woocommerce', 'translate_woocommerce_strings');

function translate_woocommerce_strings($string) {

    switch ($string) {
        case 'Apply coupon':
            $string = 'Apply koupon';
            break;
        case 'Update cart':
            $string = 'Update kart';
            break;
    }
    return $string;
}
```